# Flutter Inconsistent Layout

Tags: android, ios, flutter

so I have a weird issue. My flutter app renders extremely different for Android and iOS. I have several other flutter apps so this issue is quite strange. Take a look at the screenshots below:

This is how it looks on Android, proper. The way I intended for it to look.

[image: Android Screenshot]

Now this is the iOS screenshot. Look at how the text is overlapping on "Hi Tshepo...."

[image: iOS Screenshot]

I am not sure why its rendering differently on iOS. Here is the code:

```
return Theme(
      data: Styles.getCustomInputThemeData(),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Modules.buildErrorMessageLayout(model.getLaunchModel().getLoginError),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                model.getLaunchModel().getExistingUser().getWelcomeBackMessage,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: _passwordFieldFocusNode,
              onFieldSubmitted: (_) =>onTap,
              initialValue: "123ABc",
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(SmartelIcons.locked_5,
                    color: Colors.grey[700]),
                hintText: Constants.PASSWORD,
                labelText: Constants.PASSWORD,
              ),
              validator: (val) => Modules.validateTextField(val),
              onSaved: (val) => model.getUser().password = val,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => model.getLaunchModel().resetExistingUser(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  Constants.NOT_ME_BUTTON,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant try wrapping your `Text` inside a `Flexible`. Then wrap that around a `Row` to make it adjust on the x axis, and center it.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: Text(
          model.getLaunchModel().getExistingUser().getWelcomeBackMessage,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```